# Expose spark-ui with zeppelin on kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, apache-zeppelin

First of all I'm pretty new on all this (kubernetes, ingress, spark/zeppelin ...) so my apologies if this is obvious. I tried searching here, documentations etc but couldn't find anything.

I am trying to make the spark interpreter ui accessible from my zeppelin notebook running on kubernetes.
Following what I understood from here: http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-preview1/quickstart/kubernetes.html, my ingress yaml looks something like this:

Ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-zeppelin-server-http
http
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-zeppelin.my-domain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: zeppelin-server
          servicePort: 8080
  - host: '*.my-zeppelin.my-domain'
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: spark-guovyx
          servicePort: 4040
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

My issue here is that I need to rely on the service-name (in this case spark-guovyx) being set to the interpreter pod name in order to have the UI show up. However since this name is bound to change / have different ones (i.e. I have one interpreter per user + interpreters are frequently restarted) obviously I cannot rely on setting it manually. My initial thought was to use some kind of wildcard naming for the serviceName but turns out ingress/kubernetes don't support that. Any ideas please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new service and leverage the **interpreterSettingName** label of the spark master pod. When zeppelin creates a master spark pod it adds this label and its value is **spark**. I am not sure if it will work for more than one pods in a per user per interpreter setting. Below is the code for service, do let me know how it behaves for per user per interpreter.

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: sparkUI
spec:
  ports:
    - name: spark-ui
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4040
      targetPort: 4040
  selector:
    interpreterSettingName: spark
  clusterIP: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

And then you can have your ingress as:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-zeppelin-server-http
http
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-zeppelin.my-domain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: zeppelin-server
          servicePort: 8080
  - host: '*.my-zeppelin.my-domain'
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: sparkUI
          servicePort: 4040
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Also do checkout this repo https://github.com/cuebook/cuelake, it is still in early stage of development but would love to hear your feedback.

Comment: Hello Vikrant, I upvoted/accepted your answer because it indeed fixed my problem, thank you so much it was driving me mad ! Cuelake looks interesting for sure, in my case I'm more trying to deploy spark/zeppelin as a data research platform for several users than a ELT-like tool.